# How to replace listview with Recyclerview while fetching data from mysql database using AsyncResponse implementation

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

**below code fetch the data from database and display the data in listview I want to display it in Recyclerview for better performance**

I just want to change my listview with Recyclerview without effecting my entire code

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AsyncResponse {



 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this,this );
            taskRead.execute("http://10.0.3.2/customer/product.php");

}


 @Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {

        productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);





        BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
        dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
                return product.name;
            }
        });





        FunDapter<Product> adapter  = new FunDapter<>(MainActivity.this,productList,R.layout.homedatalist,dict);

        lvProduct =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
        lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);    


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the 'ProductList' to the adapter you will have to make for the recyclerview. Basically prepare all the data appropriately and then send it to the recyclerview adapter. There you redistribute the individual information to the various views.

1. Implement the parameters for the recyclerview (like layout)
2. You will have to prepare the data for the recyclerview (Should be same as the listview)
3. Pass this data to the adapter specifically for recyclerview (look at tutorials)
4. Remove code used for the listview.
5. Unchanged parts- getting json from the server/website. Manipulating/Preparing the data for the recyclerview.